# How to programmatically construct components at runtime using C++ Builder?

Tags: runtime, components, c++builder

Very basic C++ Builder question. I want to create a TButton at runtime. I would have thought that the following code would do it, but I see no button on the form:

```
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner)  
{  
    TButton* b = new TButton(this);  
    b->Height = 100;  
    b->Width = 100;  
    b->Left = 0;   
    b->Top = 0;   
    b->Caption = "Testing";  
    b->Visible = true;  
    b->Enabled = true;  
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the button's  `Parent` (the surface it displays on):

```
b->Parent = this;
```

Comment: Doh! (I said it was very basic) Thanks Ken.

Comment: No problem. It's a common issue with people new to the VCL (which means both Delphi and C++Builder). :-)

Comment: To add some explanation: VCL controls are arranged in a Parent-Child hierarchy (each control has zero or more Children). This relationship is solely for the purposes of drawing: the top level of the hierarchy is the window, and it will have a bunch of controls as its children, and each of those may have their own children etc.; so to draw the window, the main loop will tell the main window to draw itself; then the main window draws itself and then calls the draw function on each of its Children.

Comment: This is completely separate to the `Owner` property which controls who calls `delete` on the control. `new TButton(this)` sets the new button's `Owner` but not its `Parent` and it means that when the Form is `delete`d then the Form's destructor will delete this new control so there is not a memory leak.