# How can I add components at run time in C++ Builder XE7

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe7

I want to add some components at run time. I use C++ Builder XE 7 and vcl. How can I add components to the class Form in run time? Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically construct components at runtime using C++ Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441837/how-to-programmatically-construct-components-at-runtime-using-c-builder)

Comment: yeah, that was what i meant. Sorry i am new in vcl.. can you please post an code example? that would be great. thank you

Comment: See the post I linked in my edited comment. The question has sample code, missing only one line (that is explained in the answer to that question).

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Thank you. 
Here is an example:

```
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner)  
{  
    TButton* b = new TButton(this);  
    b->Parent = this;
    b->Height = 100;  
    b->Width = 100;  
    b->Left = 0;   
    b->Top = 0;   
    b->Caption = "Testing";  
    b->Visible = true;  
    b->Enabled = true;  
}
```

Comment: I've clearly marked your question as being a duplicate of a previous question, which means it should be closed (not answered).